# JQuery 1.4 to 1.12 Selector in not a function with .Not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-migrate

We are migrating from 1.4 to 1.12 (and then to 3.0).

Why I am receiving this error in 1.12:

TypeError: $allButtons.not(...).button is not a function

```
    var $allButtons = $('.HTMLInputButtonMinWidth')
    .add('.HTMLInputButton')
    .add('.ButtonAcceptReject')
    .add(':submit')
    .add(':button')
    .add('span.spanButton')
    .not('.dontmakemeabutton')

    var $allSpans = $allButtons.filter('span.spanButton')
```

Then get the error on this line

```
    var $buttons = $allButtons.not($allSpans).button();
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the plugin which is responsible for adding a `.button()` method to jQuery (probably jQuery UI).

Comment: Well it appears to be deprecated but I am not sure what to replace it with??